# What is the difference between the movesets of Regular Kakashi and Sharingan Kakashi?

Tags: naruto-clash-of-ninjas

I cannot find any difference in the move set between Sharingan Kakashi and Regular Kakashi. When you compare nine-tails Naruto and his Regular form, you can find obvious graphical and move set differences, but I'm completely baffled when it comes to the differences between the forms of Kakashi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/589355-naruto-clash-of-ninja/faqs/23319) from GameFAQs states the difference:

> sharingan kakashi moves are the same
>   except that his kunai throws deal much
>   more damage and have a reddish aura to
>   it.
>
> Also his counter is different, this is one of the best counters in the game.
>   No it doesn't deal damage but there is
>   no delay.

I edited the second half of the quote... if you read the source you'll know why.

Comment: Why is it saying something about copying supers?